# Mapping another file using python spark

Tags: python, pyspark

Being new to spark and python, trying out some basic stuff to print the count and max of employee data.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Hello") \
    .config("World") \
    .getOrCreate()


sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.textFile("employee.txt").map(lambda l: l.split('::')),
    ["employeeid","deptid","salary"]
)
df.registerTempTable("df")

mostEmpDept = sqlContext.sql("""select deptid, cntDept from (
                                            select deptid, count(*) as cntDept, max(count(*)) over () as maxcnt 
                                            from df 
                                            group by deptid) as tmp
                                            where tmp.cntDept = tmp.maxcnt""")

mostEmpDept.show()
```

THe above code results in giving me the deptid with highest number of employees, which looks as below

```
+-------+--------+                                                              
|deptid |cntDept |
+-------+--------+
|    10 |       7|
+-------+--------+
```

Now, I have another file which contains all the deptid with their names, How do I map this result to the other file and print the deptid 10 name ? The other file looks as below

```
10::Marketing
20::Finance
30::HumanResource
40::HouseKeeping
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below:

```
sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.textFile("employee.txt").map(lambda l: l.split('::')),
    ["employeeid","deptid","salary"]
)
df.registerTempTable("df")

dept = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.textFile("dept.txt").map(lambda l: l.split('::')),
    ["deptid","deptname"]
)
dept.registerTempTable("dept")

mostEmpDept = sqlContext.sql("""select deptid, cntDept from (
                                            select deptid, count(*) as cntDept, max(count(*)) over () as maxcnt 
                                            from df 
                                            group by deptid) as tmp
                                            where tmp.cntDept = tmp.maxcnt""")

mostEmpDept.registerTempTable('mostEmpDept')

final_df= sqlContext.sql("select a.deptid, b.deptname from mostEmpDept a inner join dept b on a.deptid=b.deptid")

final_df.show()
```

If you want to save it, use

```
final_df.saveAsTextFile('Location')
```